# TypeScript Array traversing Reverse & Forward showing same values?

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

array printing same items either access by reverse/forward loops
**NOTE** No built-in functionality will be used

```
let sentence = "A Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the lazy Dog";
let char;let space = ' ';let array = [] ;let word = '' ;

//Creating Array of Words
for (let c=0;c<sentence.length;c++){
  char=sentence.charAt(c);
  if (char != space) {
    word+=char;
  }
  else {
    array.push(word);
    word = ''
  }
}
if (word){
  array.push(word)
  word ='';
}

console.log("Before Sort:\\n"+array);

//Sorting Array
for (let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
  for(let j = 0 ; j < array.length ; j++){
    if(array[i] < array[j]){
      word = array[j];
      array[j] = array[i];
      array[i] = word;
    }
  }
}
console.log("Ascending Order:\\n"+array);

//Printing in descending Order
for (let d=array.length;d==0;d--){   //trying to print in reverse order 
console.log(array[d]);
}
console.log("Descending Order:\\n"+array);
```

**Result:**

```
Before Sort:
A,Quick,Brown,Fox,Jumps,Over,the,lazy,Dog

Ascending Order:
A,Brown,Dog,Fox,Jumps,Over,Quick,lazy,the

Decending Order:
A,Brown,Dog,Fox,Jumps,Over,Quick,lazy,the
```

Comment: It looks like you've struggled with posting code and added a lot of unnecessary backslashes. Please use the "edit" link on the question, remove the code block, and do this: 1. Copy your code in your editor. 2. Paste it exactly as-is in the question text. 3. Select the code in the question text. Press Ctrl+K to mark it as code. No need to escape anything within it. Please see the **`[?]`** in the editor toolbar for more formatting help.

Comment: Until you do that, it's really hard to help, because it's not clear what the actual code is.

Comment: @Scott - Frankly, I'm not sure we should try to fix this for them, because we don't know for sure **what** their actual code is.

Comment: You don't do anything to alter `array` between printing the (supposedly) ascending & descending versions.

Comment: If you really have `for (let d=array.length;d==0;d--){` in your code, that won't do anything unless the array is empty. The condition `d==0` in a `for` loop means "keep looping as long as `d` is equal to `0`." To loop **forward** through an array: `for (const value of array) { /*...use value...*/ }`. To look backward through an array: `for (let d = array.length - 1; d >= 0; --d) { const value = array[d]; /*...use value */ }`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: And yet, you try and fix it :)

Comment: @ScottHunter - I've tried to help the OP, not fix the question. I haven't made any edits at all. Sorry, "fix this for them" may have been unclear. :-)

Comment: Extremely Sorry for inconvenience, you pointed me correct mistake i have corrected it and i will  takecare as you guided
Regards